# jquery update multiple field

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, textbox

is there something wrong in the code? **its not actually updating all textinput** but only updating the first input id=1 after save is clicked!

HTML Markup:

```
<input type="text" id="1">
<input type="text" id="2">
<input type="text" id="3">
<input type="text" id="4">
<input type="text" id="5">
<input type="text" id="6">
```

JQUERY:

```
 $('#save_affiliate').live('click',function() {
            var $inputs = $('#affiliate_form');
            $inputs.each(function(){
                var counter = $(this).find("input[type=text]").length;
                var af_value = $(this).find("input[type=text]").attr("value");
                var af_id = $(this).find("input[type=text]").attr("id");
                if(counter>0){
                    $.post("include/setting.php?affiliate",{id:af_id, text_value:af_value, count:counter}, function(data){
                        if(data.success) {
                                $('.err').html(data.message).fadeIn('slow');
                        } else {$('.err').html(data.message).fadeIn('slow');}
                    },"json");
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

PHP:

```
$counter = $_POST['count'];
$value = $_POST['text_value'];  
$id = $_POST['id'];
$i = 0;
if ($counter != 0) :
    while($i<$counter) :
    $db->query("UPDATE affiliate SET d_percent='$value' WHERE id_affiliate='$id'");     
    endwhile;

    $data["message"] = "Affiliate percentage value has been changed!";
    $data['success'] = true;
endif;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `.each()` on your form, but you need to use it on your inputs:

```
$('#save_affiliate').live('click', function() {
    var $inputs = $('#affiliate_form').find("input[type=text]");
    $inputs.each(function(i) {
        var counter = $inputs.length;
        var af_value = $(this).attr("value");
        var af_id = $(this).attr("id");
        $.post("include/setting.php?affiliate", {
            id: af_id,
            text_value: af_value,
            count: counter
        }, function(data) {
            if (data.success) {
                $('.err').html(data.message).fadeIn('slow');
            } else {
                $('.err').html(data.message).fadeIn('slow');
            }
        }, "json");
    });
    return false;
});
```

You also don't need to check for `counter > 0` because the function won't run if there aren't any `input[type=text]`.  If you mean the count key to be the index of the input, then use the `i` parameter passed to the each function.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$(this).find("input[type=text]").each(function(index) {
// 
});
```

to manipulate every captured element.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in Stefan's answer, you need to use some sort of loop to iterate over each of the input elements you've got.
The reason for this is that tha `.attr()` method returns the attribute for the *first* element in the set of elements you're calling it on.
Therefore, when you're executing

```
var af_value = $(this).find("input[type=text]").attr("value");
var af_id = $(this).find("input[type=text]").attr("id");
```

you're only retrieving the id & values for the first input element that is matched by your selector; in your case it is the one with id=1.